# Triangle's 1 km exclusion zone

Tags: triangles, circles

In my IGCSE textbook, there is a question:

> A long time ago Dulani found an island shaped like a triangle with 3 straight shores of length 3 km, 4 km, 5 km. He said nobody could come within 1 km of his shore. What was the area of his exclusion zone?

I know that this is a right angle triangle. By applying $3*1+4*1+5*1+(1^2)*π$ because of three rectangles and exterior angles, I get 15.1 as my answer. How come the answer is 14.8?

Comment: The interior angles are $\approx 53^{\circ}$ and $\approx 37^{\circ}$, and therefore the exterior angles are $\approx 126^{\circ}$ and $143^{\circ}$. That plus the $90^{\circ}$ indeed gets the full circle.

Comment: Why isn't the right angle counted?

Comment: My final thought is that the answer you wrote should be correct.

Comment: Maybe it is the book that's wrong. But I want to know for sure.I guess it may be 15.14, maybe book is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the sea that is excluded consists of three rectangular regions along the shoreline, and three circular sectors at the corners. These three circular sectors add up to one full circle. This yields
$$3\times1+4\times1+5\times1+\pi\approx15.14...,$$
just as you found. The answer you quote seems incorrect.

The only different interpretation I can imagine is that you should also count part of the interior of the island. But this only increases the area of the exclusion zone.

Comment: I don't see how that would explain any disrepancy between the results. The sum of the angles of the exterior partial circles is anyway $360^{\circ}$.

Comment: Can you explain further about how a formula would change if the exterior angle is $>90$ and $<180$?

Comment: @MattiP. You are right, I overcounted. The answer is corrected now, but still does not agree with any of the provided answers.

Comment: It helps loads to draw a picture. It could be that these differences are due to us not having defined what we mean by exterior angles, exactly. What I mean, are the angles of the sections that form arcs. For example, the four angles at one of the corners is $90+53+90+126$ degrees. I count the $126$ degrees as the exterior angle.

Comment: Yes matti.I see external angle as 180 - interior angle.

Comment: I guess it may be 15.14, maybe book is wrong.